# Determine the numbers $n$ that are orders of elements of $\mathbb{Z}^3 / H$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^3/H$, where $H$ is a subgroup that has been generated by $(2,0,2), (6,6,6) $ and $(8,36,38)$.

How can I solve this problem? I don't know where to start.

A related question would be what are the possible orders of elements of the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/60\mathbb{Z}$

What are the strategies for both problems? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the first part to the same form as the second:
Observe that if $H$ is generated by $(2,0,2),(6,6,6),(8,36,38)$ then you can 'row-reduce' it in the following manner: $H$ is also generated by $(2,0,2),(0,6,0),(0,36,30)$ and so 
$H=\langle(2,0,2),(0,6,0),(0,0,30)\rangle$.
If you denote $a=(1,0,1)$, $b=(0,1,0)$ and $c=(0,0,1)$ then, clearly $a,b,c$ generate $\mathbb{Z}^3$, and so thier images $\bar{a},\bar{b},\bar{c}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^3/H$ generate $\mathbb{Z}^3/H$.
From here you can show that $\mathbb{Z}^3/H\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}2&0&2\\
6&6&6\\
8&36&38\end{pmatrix}=360\implies \left|\Bbb Z^3/H\right|=360\;,\;\;\text{ so}\ldots$$

For the second question we have a more basic approach: any element here is of the form

$$(a,b,c)\;$$

where $\,a\,$ has order two, $\,b\,$ has order $\;6\;$ and $\;c\;$ has order $\;60\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}= \overline {\mathbb Z}_m$$ $$o(x)=m ,o(y)=n, o(z)=p \Rightarrow o((x,y,z))=\ scm(m,n,p)$$
$$\large{o}([x]_m)=\frac{m}{\gcd(m,x)}$$